# How are golang projects packaged for deployment?

Tags: go

Coming from a JVM background I would like to know how to deploy a golang project to production. Is there an equivalent of a JAR file?

Is there a standalone package manager that can be installed on server and a dependency manifest file which can be run to bring down all dependencies on the server. I specifically do not want to have to build the project on the server as we can't have any compilers etc on production boxes.

thanks.

Comment: You just copy the binary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I you run `go install <pkg>`, the binary will be placed in `$GOPATH/bin`. You can copy that binary to another machine that has the same OS and architecture.

You can also change into the directory that includes the `main` package and just run `go build`. The binary will be placed in the current directory.

There are no dependencies in a Go binary for you to track. It is statically linked. (Some system libraries may be dynamically linked, but if you are running on the same OS, this shouldn't be a problem.)

Comment: Yep - it's that simple. If your app needs to be deployed with additional asset files, config files etc etc, you might simply put them all into a tarball with the binary. Alternatively, some assets might be embedded into the binary with a tool such as https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata.

Comment: @RobNapier What if the machine to be deployed has different configuration (OS)

Comment: You would need to cross-compile in that case. http://dave.cheney.net/2015/03/03/cross-compilation-just-got-a-whole-lot-better-in-go-1-5